# Is there a simpler, more poetic term for "the detritus of animal life"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Forensic scientists collect DNA from cast-off bits of people such as skin cells, blood, and hair.  In many magical traditions, such as Voudoun, bits of a person can be used to direct a spell - blood, nail clippings, saliva, etc.

Is there a term that covers "all the bits and pieces that make up a person or animal"?  The context is mythology, so an obsolete or archaic word would fit in just fine.

*Detritus* is the closest I've come up with, but I'm not quite happy with it.  I don't necessarily mean "bits which have been cast off," but really all the elements of an animal.  A word or phrase which means "fur, skin, feathers, and/or bone" would be about right.  "Organic matter" has the right technical meaning, but it's, well, too technical.

Clarification: I don't actually need a single word, a short phrase would be fine.  There doesn't seem to be a tag for "word-requests" alone.

Comment: How about "biological matter"?

Comment: Wow, great responses all around!  More than I expected.  Thank you all for the contributions.

Comment: Re "There doesn't seem to be a tag for "word-requests" alone", [tag:word-requests] is registered as a [synonym](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) of [tag:single-word-requests] and converts to it automatically.

Comment: @jwpat7: Yeah, that's exactly what happened.  Cool, then I won't get jumped on for using a tag loosely?  I've found some SE groups to be... prickly.

Comment: There are people voting to close single-word-requests that don't include explanation of context or rationale for needing a single word, and for various other reasons not mentioned in faq but discussed in [meta].  If a phrase is ok too, use [tag:phrase-requests] tag too.

Comment: No one seems to have addressed this, but 'detritus' sounds really inappropriate. It has a poor connotation, a fancy word for trash or refuse. So 'detritus of animal life' should definitely -not- be used for what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The words *tissue* or *flesh* seem to me nearly general enough for much of "the bits and pieces that make up a person or animal", but *flesh* typically does not connote fur, hair, feathers, bone; and in [dictionary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/tissue) definitions, *tissue* seems overly specific:

> Biology - an aggregate of similar cells and cell products forming a definite kind of structural material with a specific function, in a multicellular organism.

Some other terms to consider:

- *[dander](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dander)* - "Hair follicles and dead skin shed from mammals."
- *stuff of life* - flesh and other bits of life - (note, not *[staff of life](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/staff_of_life)*, which is *bread*)
- *[corpus](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/corpus)* - "the body of a person or animal, especially when dead" (while *[corpse](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/corpse)* specifically refers to a dead body, a corpus may be alive)
- *[mortal coil](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mortal_coil)* - "The physical body of man (containing the spirit inside) ... "what Fletcher calls the ‘case of flesh’""

A minor problem with that last is that nearly any use of it must be overshadowed by Shakespeare's

> For in that sleep of death, what dreams may come,
>   When we have shuffled off this mortal coil,
>   Must give us pause.

Comment: Wow, several good answers!  "Flesh" is close, it has a nice Jung-ian ring to it.  I really like "corpus" too, though it implies (to me, anyway), a whole body, whereas (putting a really fine hair on it), I'm looking for *parts* of a body.

Comment: I'm going with "corpus."  Thank you!

Comment: You could go with a string of these, e.g.: "corpus, flesh, nails and dander..."

Answer (score 1):

[Constituents](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/constituent) might fit the bill.

Answer (score 0):

*Genomic* is the adjective derived from genome.  Biologically speaking, it fits the bill, although it may lack the archaic overtones you seek.

Comment: Yeah, that's a bit technical-sounding, as is "biological matter".  You are quite right, of course; it striking that the powers and processes of genomics mirrors ancient superstition so closely.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [*somatic*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/somatic) ("of the body") would work?

Comment: The first thing that that word brings to mind is "psycho-somatic," which is unfortunate.  Your link brought me to "corporal," though, which is very close to what I had in mind.  The noun form, "somato" has a nice ring to it.

Answer (score 0):

I think "remains" or "mortal remains" hit the target.

Answer (score 0):

I think OP was on the right track with *detritus*. [Here](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=bio-detritus&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22biodetritus%22&pbx=1&oq=%22biodetritus%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=3&gs_upl=26098l26098l3l26376l1l1l0l0l0l0l59l59l1l1l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=4c3a76122614ebc0&biw=1359&bih=885) are 3510 results in Google Books for **"biodetritus"** (plus [another 192](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=bio-detritus&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22bio-detritus%22&pbx=1&oq=%22bio-detritus%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=3&gs_upl=73226l73226l4l73538l1l1l0l0l0l0l54l54l1l1l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=4c3a76122614ebc0&biw=1359&bih=885) for *"bio-detritus"*).

Looking at how the word is used [here](http://www.jstor.org/pss/2460137), it's obviously *not* restricted to material shed during normal life. But equally, it's not restricted to people and/or higher animals either. To nail that, OP would need some appropriate qualifying term such as *forensic biodetritus*, or *human biodetritus*.

I don't suppose there would be a term *also* covering the relevant material for a voodoo witch doctor to cast a hex on, say, somebody's dog. OP would probably need to refer to that as *the subject's biodetritus*, having established by context exactly who/what *the subject* means.

Answer (score 0):

The technical term (with the least specialization is

**specimen**

which has a slightly clincal feel to it. An even more technically technical term is

**biospecimen**.

There doesn't seem to be any enclosing concept name (hypernym) for the concept you're looking for: nail clippings, hair, blood, menstrual blood, ear wax that are associated with magical practices. No self-respecting voodoo priest says 'go fetch me a specimen', they say 'go fetch me some hair or nail clippings or something like that...yes, yes, ear wax will do'.